# Angular Universal SSR, only renders for certain paths

Tags: angular, nestjs, meta-tags, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

## Problem

So after having dealt with the complications of Angular SSR, I have managed to install it and it works great on my project. However, when using `routing`, SSR does not fully work on a specific route. I am able to generate the meta tags in one out of two components however when loading the other component it does not show the meta tags. If obstructed in this process, and reloaded again, the component work as if nothing has happened however meta tags are still not generated - Basically, Angular SSR does not load the metatags for a specific component.

## Example / Recreation

So let's say you have a component named `alpha` and another called `beta` - Both components have the same code running. However, they have both different `routes` - You have attempted to generate the metatags for each component perhaps in a `service`- `alpha` loads in quick with all the meta tags also on the first time load as well. `beta` does not. No matter what code or `route` you change, `beta` still hasn't generated any meta tags.

## Question

How do I solve the load for both components? Any leads, suggestions are very much appreciated.

#### Enviroment

I am using NestJS and Angular (Obviously).

OBS: I noticed I get the error in promises. If I simply set SEO tags, it works. But then it can only be static metatags.

[Screen of routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ7GS.png)

[Generation of tags (Service)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwX90.png)

Comment: It would help to see your routing setup and the code that populates meta tags. It's hard to troubleshoot a scenario.

Comment: Check that there is no error in the console server side. If there is none, add debug statements to your code (routing, init, api calls) and try to identify what's going on

Comment: There are errors in the console, however, the same errors appear on the other component. I have tried to delete the code that generates the errors to see if having no errors helped anything, but it did not do any good. I shall update the post with code from the routing setup.